# Vim syntax highlighting in terminal only affects the text background and not the text colour

Tags: vim, terminal, cygwin

I have just started using Vim in a terminal (PuTTY or MinTTY), after always using gVim. However, when using syntax highlighting, rather than the actual text colour changing appropriately, its background is changed to whatever colour -- and it looks horrible!

I've set my terminal to use 256 colours and downloaded a 256 colour colour scheme. I checked that the `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` settings are as I expect, but I still get this problem... Is this a Vim or a terminal configuration issue?

Comment: You've set your terminal to use 256 colors, but are you setting the TERM env variable to a 256 color capable terminal?  My guess is you've probably just got it set to xterm or the like and need to set it to xterm-256color (just an example).

Comment: It's in my `.profile`, but apparently that's not getting executed. So I tried `export TERM='xterm-256color'` from the shell prompt and tried Vim again, but same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many color schemes have features that are only supported in gvim/macvim. Some color schemes such as solarized, can be configured to support 256 color terminals using a setting such as `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`.  For other color schemes, look at plugins like this one: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1809 and this one: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390

Comment: I'm using [attempting to] `wombat256`, which says in the comments "Modified version of wombat for 256-color terminals"; so I assume it's meant to work :P

Comment: That sounds reasonable... but I wouldn't be surprised if you had challenges getting certain color schemes to work in the terminal properly. I know I have had to experiment with plugins to transform the colorscheme for the terminal... eventually I went with solarized.

Comment: Solarized actually looks like a pretty sweet colour scheme...maybe I'll just use that instead ;)

Comment: ...Just got home, installed `Pathogen` (I hadn't got around to it yet) and `Solarized`, with the settings you recommended and...voila! Beautiful :) Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster. `g:solarized_termcolors` was already set to `256`, and resetting it didn't fix the problem.